# Can you canvas.drawText() emojis with stroke?

Tags: android, kotlin, canvas, android-canvas, paint

Can you canvas.drawText() emojis with stroke.?

I'm shocked Android doesn't natively support drawing emojis.
The fact you need an external library EmojiCompat is pretty mind-blowing.
After some experimentation...

This works (renders the emoji):

```
paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);
CharSequence fireEmoji = EmojiCompat.get().process("\uD83D\uDD25");
canvas.drawText(fireEmoji.toString(), x, y, paint);
```

This doesn't (renders nothing):

```
paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
CharSequence fireEmoji = EmojiCompat.get().process("\uD83D\uDD25");
canvas.drawText(fireEmoji.toString(), x, y, paint);
```

This doesn't (renders nothing):

```
paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL_AND_STROKE);
CharSequence fireEmoji = EmojiCompat.get().process("\uD83D\uDD25");
canvas.drawText(fireEmoji.toString(), x, y, paint);
```

Adding a stroke around the emojis in my app is pretty important.
I currently use hundreds of images instead of drawing the emojis directly because I need the stroke.
Is there a way to do this through this method or another method.?